# The operation has timed out--Exception in a WCF Service RSS

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Hello I have created a WCF Service which has a method as

```
public List<AppharborDbModel.MMTS_Stations> GetStations()
{
    db = new AppharborDbModel.AppHarborDBEntities();
    var x = from n in db.MMTS_Stations select n;
    return x.ToList<AppharborDbModel.MMTS_Stations>();
}
```

When I'm consuming it from client application I'm getting the following exception...

```
TimeOutException

The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:58.8880000.        Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

The operation has timed out

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out

Source Error: 


Line 601:        
Line 602:        public  System.Collections.Generic.List<ServiceWebReference.MMTS_Stations> GetStations() {
Line 603:            return base.Channel.GetStations();
Line 604:        }
Line 605:    }
```

And I'm using "WCF Service" web template in .Net 4.0 which has implicit endpoints and bindings.. So there is no end points r bundings in web.config.

Where should I change TimeOut value?

Answer (score 0):

Change your timeouts on the server that is hosting your WCF endpoint:

[Explaination of different timeout types](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/84551e45-19a2-4d0d-bcc0-516a4041943d/)